# Append internal traffic with ?internal=true based on IP address

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to append any url with ?internal=true if the IP address is one of mine (where x.x.x.x = the IP)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^x.x.x.x$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?internal=true [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is nearly perfect, I just made a tiny modification:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^x\.x\.x\.x$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?internal=true [END,QSA]
```

The specific issue with your exact code is that you omit the actual path component of the requested URL when rewriting. Instead you need to preserve it using the `$1` reference.

*The "x.x.x.x" obviously is meant as a placeholder for an IP address.* 
When matching for IP addresses keep in mind that the quadrupel notation you use only matches IPV4 addresses. Many networks started to use the advanced IPV6 in the mean time. You will have to adjust your code once your own network switches.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for this. I ended up shifting to an anchor using your code. I seem to get a 500 error unless I put an R in there, in which case it 301's me.  here is the updated code, thanks again!:                                                                                            
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^208.185.200.146$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1#internal [L,NE,QSA,R]
</IfModule>

Comment: For the actual reason why you get a http status 500 you need to check in the error log file your http server writes for exactly that purpose. The `R` flag means "external redirection", it was not clear from the question that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: About the anchor: I fail to see what sense that should make. If you use the `R` flag, then your client is redirected. An anchor may well be part of a URL, sure, _but it is never sent to the server_ , so you have not gained anything.

Comment: The http status 500 _most likely_ is called by an endless rewriting loop cause by the old `L` flag you use instead of the better `END` flag. You can prevent that using an additional `RewriteCond`.